# The logical error or test case error in python

Tags: python-3.x

**Handling Expection**

**The full question is of Hackerrank. I have passed all the test cases but one test case is failing. I don't know why. Logic is correct. Please help me**

**test case in given question**

*
4500(membership fee)

3(number of installments)

Welcome boy(name)

*

**my code is**

```
def Library(memberfee, installment, book):
    if(installment > 3):
        print("Maximum Permitted Number of Installments is 3")
    
    else:
        if(installment == 0):
            print("Number of Installments cannot be Zero.")
        else:
            print("Amount per Installment is  {}".format(memberfee/installment))
            ListOfBooks = ["philosophers stone", "chamber of sec rets", "prisoner of azkaban", "goblet of fire", "order of phoenix", "half blood price", "deathly hallows 1", "deathly hallows2"]
    
            book =  book.lower()
            if book in ListOfBooks:
                print("It is available in this section")
            else:
                print("No such book exists in this section")
if __name__ == '__main__':
    
    memberfee = int(input())
    installment = int(input())
    book = input()
    
    try:
        Library(memberfee,installment,book)
        
    except ZeroDivisionError as e:
        print(e)
    except ValueError as e:
        print(e)
    except NameError as e:
        print(e)
```

**i think the problem may be here

```
 print("Amount per Installment is  {}".format(memberfee/installment))
```

**

**The question is.....**

*Library

This exception handling scenario deals with the exceptional cases that arise in a typical library interface of a Town library.

O

1

About the Library Interface

This is a typical interface provided in the library, which takes 3 inputs from the library members, sequentially. They are:

1. memberfee - Membership fee for the library for the next financial year, which can be paid in installments.
2. installment - Number of installments chosen to pay the Membership fee. 3. book- Name of the book the member looks for in the 'Harry Potter' Section.

23

24

25

26

27

28

29

30

Note

All the above inputs except 'book' are Integers.

Write the function definition as follows, for the function 'Library', that takes all the above 3 inputs as its parameters:

The maximum permitted number of installments to pay the annual membership fee is '3'.

1. Raise ValueError exception if the input for the number of installments is greater than '3' and Print a Message. The message to the user must be, "Maximum Permitted Number of Installments is 3", The amount per installment is calculated by dividing the Membership fee by the number of installments. 2. Raise ZeroDivision Error exception if the input for the number of installments is equal to '0' and Print a Message. The message to the user must be, "Number of Installments cannot be Zero." else

1

> #!/bin/python

10

11

def Library (

if(insta

prin

else:

if(

els

(memberfee

sec rets",

phoenix",

hallows 2"1

Print the amount per installment as "Amount per Installment is 3000.0".

12

13

The 'Harry Potter' book section contains the following books only:

14

ALL

1

15

philosophers stone

16

. chamber of secrets

17

• prisoner of azkaban

18

19

• goblet of fire

• order of phoenix

half blood prince

deathly hallows 1

21

23

20

24

• deathly hallows 2*

Answer (score 0):

```
def Library(memberfee,installment,book):
    # Write your code here
    #print(memberfee)
    #print(installment)
    #print(book)
    
    if installment > 3:
        raise(ValueError("Maximum Permitted Number of Installments is 3"))  
    
    if installment == 0:
        raise(ZeroDivisionError("Number of Installments cannot be Zero."))  
    else:
        print ("Amount per Installment is ", memberfee / installment)
    
    if book == 'philosophers stone' or book == 'Chamber of Secrets' or book == 'prisoner of azkaban' or book == 'Goblet of Fire' or book == 'order of phoenix' or book == 'Half Blood Prince' or book == 'Deathly Hallows 1' or  book == 'deathly hallows 2':
        print ("It is available in this section")  
    else:
        raise(NameError("No such book exists in this section"))
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Your ListofBooks contains some grammatical errors in the names of the books. Maybe that's what caused the error.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, it is just a name not matching with listofbooks.
Please try to check all the book names from listofbooks.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33455170)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).